# How to load custom cell in uitableview

Tags: ios

Can anyone please provide me tutorial for loading custom cell in uitableview. I need this in my application.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [sample tutorial](http://www.highoncoding.com/Videos/823_Creating_a_Custom_UITableViewCell.aspx) might help. One of the ways is to extend the UITableViewCell class and use a custom .XIB for your custom cell. Well, that is the general idea.

Comment: I have seen this tutorial before but was making mistaking in making demo file. But this time it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try The Below Code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCellIdentifier";



    SPHTableCell *cell = (SPHTableCell *)[data_Table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[SPHTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    return cell;
}
```